# Call WWW outside main thread

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I'm using Parse SDK for Unity to get some files and save on my resources directory. When I call parse.findAsync() it creates another task and its impossible for me to call WWW to download the URL I got from parse. I need to:

- Call Parse
- Get Parse Info
- Call www for every file I got from parse
- Wait everything completes;
- Return Result;

I tried this:

```
      public IEnumerator GetXXXAsync(String objectId){
        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("xxx").WhereEqualTo("yyy", ParseObject.
        CreateWithoutData("zzz", objectId));

        List<String> urlList = new List<String>();
        Album album = null;

        query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                                       {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            Task task = Task.FromResult(0);
            foreach (var result in t.Result)
            {
                ParseObject obj  = result;      

                ParseFile file = (ParseFile)obj.Get<ParseFile>("image");
                if(file != null){
                    urlList.Add(file.Url.ToString());
                    tasks.Add(GetImageAsync(file.Url.ToString(), "image.png")); 
                }               


            }

            // finished.
            return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }).Unwrap().ContinueWith(_ =>
         {
            gameManager.SendOk();

        });

        return null;
      }

      private WWW WaitForImage(String url, string filename) {   

        WWW www = new WWW( url );
        while(!www.isDone){
            Debug.Log("Waiting");
        }
        Utils.SaveFileFromTexture(www.texture, (gameManager.GetResourcesPath() + "/Textures/" + filename));
        Debug.Log("Saving file ");
        return www;     


    }


    public Task<WWW> GetImageAsync(String url, string filename) {
        var task = new TaskCompletionSource<WWW>();
        Debug.Log("GetImageAsync " + filename);
        task.SetResult(WaitForImage(url, filename));
        return task.Task;
    }
```

I Tried to get a IEnumerator instead of a WWW, but I always get WWW "could not be called outside main thread". Is there anything I can do to call WWW outside main thread? Or anything else?

Tks,

Comment: No way around it.  Either use a `coroutine` to run `WWW` "asynchronously" (as asynchronous as Unity can be) or find a 3rd party download tool.

Comment: Quick question. How are you planning to use downloaded resources if they are not part of compiled application resource files?

Comment: @Alex you can load images at runtime using www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texTmp); and that can be used for a url or a file path.  or for models you could make a importer like this one for runtime http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ObjImporter

Comment: @Shredder2500 +1! You learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/90128-Unity-Threading-Helper) to Run WWW on the main thread after your async stuff is done.  Or you could use webclient in the system.net to download on a background thread.  Dont forget you can yield the download with WWW on the main thread to make it not lockup your frames while downloading.

webclient example

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += OnChange;
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += OnCompleted;
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(download), fileAndPath);
```